# Can't INSERT date into MySQL TIMESTAMP type field results in Wrong Timezone

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, timezone

Environment: Wordpress, XAMPP Version: 7.2.10, PHP 7.2, Windows 10

I am calculating a user subscription expiration date (by adding 90 days to today's date) and storing it in a mysql database.  Although the php calculation shows the date in the right timezone, the date stored in the MySQL table is incorrect by +5 hours.  For example, "2019-10-29 14:55:01" should be "2019-10-29 9:55:01".   (FYI - other timestamp fields that have an "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" attribute are updating to the correct timezone.  Also the Windows environment is set correctly.)

I have tried the following with no success:

- setting the default timezone in my php code.
- adding the following to my .htaccess: php_value date.timezone 'America/Chicago'
- php_value date.timezone 'America/Chicago'
- adding this to php.ini:   date.timezone=America/Chicago

(Restarting Xampp after each change.)

My PHP Code:

```
$start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  //  Today's date in timestamp format.
$default_subscription_period = get_option('apr2s_user_subscription_period' );  // For now, 90 days
$user_subscription_expire_date = calculate_user_subscription_expire_date($start_date, $default_subscription_period);

echo "Start Date is  : ".$start_date."<br>";   //  Shows correct date & time in correct timezone
echo "Expire Date is : ".$user_subscription_expire_date."<br>";  //  Shows correct date & time in correct timezone

$results1 = $wpdb->insert($user_table_name, array(
"user_subscription_expire_date" => $user_subscription_expire_date,));

function calculate_user_subscription_expire_date($start_date, $subscription_period_in_days){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    $expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start_date. ' + '.$subscription_period_in_days.'days'));
    return ($expire_date);
}
```

Ideas? Thanx!

Comment: You don't need PHP to do this. SQL has date functions too.

Comment: Reason for the 2 down votes?

Comment: MySQL stores everything in UTC. You should convert into a timezone only when you display to the user.

Comment: Dharman - Then phpmyadmin may also be converting to my timezone when displaying. Thot I was seeing the stored value. Thanks.

Comment: **WARNING**: Don't use [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) to introduce data. Instead, use the WordPress [prepared statements feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) with placeholder values.

Comment: Tadman - good catch. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You should store everything in UTC for simplicity. Perform all calculations in UTC too. Convert into the right timezone only when displaying to the user, and use `DateTime()` class to do so instead of `date_default_timezone_set`. It is best to keep your default timezone set to UTC in PHP and MySQL.

You could avoid making the date calculation in PHP altogether and use SQL functions.

```
INSERT INTO $user_table_name (user_subscription_expire_date) 
    VALUES (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY))
```

or dynamically in wordpress:

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $user_table_name (user_subscription_expire_date) 
        VALUES (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL %d DAY))", 
    $default_subscription_period
) );
```

When you want to display to the user just use:

```
$date = new \DateTime($dateFromDB);
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
```